# C++ Link error unresolved external symbol in MyProject_p.obj

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I am trying to build a VC++ project and I get these LINK errors:

```
2>MyProject_p.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CStdStubBuffer2_Release@4
2>MyProject_p.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _NdrStubForwardingFunction@16
2>MyProject_p.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IUnknown_Release_Proxy@4
2>MyProject_p.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IUnknown_AddRef_Proxy@4
2>MyProject_p.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IUnknown_QueryInterface_Proxy@12
2>MyProject_p.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _NdrOleFree@4
2>MyProject_p.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _NdrOleAllocate@4
```

It is a huge project, with lots of dependent projects - that I have added in the solution, and they all build properly. 
I have performed a search in the entire solution for the above entities, like 'CStdStubBuffer2' with no result. I did find them in the MyProject_p.obj among other impossible to read items but I don't know what to do about that. I looked at similar questions but could not find anything that could help me. Could someone tell me where I can look at to troubleshoot this problem ? Thank you.

Comment: NdrOleAllocate is in RPC API, include RpcRT4.lib.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [IUnknown_Release_Proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) reference, you need to link with `RpcRT4.lib` (the other functions listed are also defined in the same lib).

Comment: also to @Isalamon : Thank you for the previous answer, out of 7 errors, I am left with _CStdStubBuffer2_Release@4 - where does this one come from ?

Comment: Don't know I am afraid. There is a function called `NdrCStdStubBuffer2_Release` but without documentation for the missing function it is impossible to know if they are equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

CStdStubBuffer2_Release gets created by other code generated by the MIDL compiler. Using command line options like "/dlldata MyProject_d.c" you'll get an additional file generated that needs to be compiled and linked with the rest of the project.

That file will contain, among other things, a line like "DLLDATA_ROUTINES( aProxyFileList, GET_DLL_CLSID )". Definitions from RpcProxy.h mean that this gets expanded and creates the CStdStubBuffer2_Release function (which is implemented using the NdrCStdStubBuffer2_Release function mentioned by @hmjd).

Answer (score 1):

RpcRT4.lib and adding the MIDL generated dlldata.c to the build did the trick for me. I also had to switch off precompiled headers for the MIDL generated source as they don't include stdafx.h